# Set value of an int pointer with python ctypes

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

How would this C++ code be translated to python ctypes?

```cpp
void SetValue(int value)
{
    typedef void(__thiscall* OriginalFn)(void*, int);
    return GetVFunc<OriginalFn>(this, 16)(this, value);
}
```

Comment: If wrapped in `extern "C" {}` (it's "C" types not "C++" types) its straightforward.  SO isn't a substitute for reading the documentation.  What have you tried?  Where did it fail?

Comment: This is obviously not valid C++ code; among other problems, it attempts to `return` a value from a function with `void` return type. Also, how are we supposed to know what e.g. `GetVFunc` is? Much more context is required in order to replicate the behaviour of code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally speaking, "please translate this code from language X to language Y" does not make an appropriate question here, because it really means "how do I use language Y to do <the thing that this language X code does>?". There are several problems: 1) this is a very indirect way to explain what the code needs to do; 2) it suggests a [lack of effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592); 3) there is a risk that it *doesn't make sense to try* to do that thing in language Y (perhaps it solves a problem that doesn't exist in language Y).

Comment: Please also read [ask] and note that this is *not a discussion forum*; we are not interested in anything to do with you as a programmer - we are interested in **the code**, and in questions about the code that are *directly* and *clearly* asked. To improve the question, please give some explanation of what *problem you hope to solve* with the code, and why there is an actual problem to solve. Show enough surrounding code to test whether the solution works; show example input; and show expected output with an explanation.